How do I select element with condition from other node
Suppose I have an HTML
<product-card>
  <card>
    <row-layout>
      <div>
        <div>
          <span>Product AAA</span>
        </div>
      </div>     
    </row-layout>
    <row-layout>
      <button>
        <span>
          <span>Create</span>
        </span>
      </button>
    </row-layout>
  </card>
  <card>
    <row-layout>
      <div>
        <div>
          <span>Product BBB</span>
        </div>
      </div>     
    </row-layout>
    <row-layout>
      <button>
        <span>
          <span>Create</span>
        </span>
      </button>
    </row-layout>
  </card>
</product-card>

So now I want to select <span>Create</span> with condition is <span>Product BBB</span> is it possible?
And what would be the correct XPath for this case, I am very new to XPath.

Do not edit the tag information back into the title, please. The tag system works very well here, and does not need any help. Please review Should questions include "tags" in their title? and [ask]. Adding the tags needlessly to the title is simply useless noise.

Something like this should work:
//span[.="Create"][preceding::span[1][.="Product BBB"]]

Target a span equals to "Create".
The first span element preceding the targeted span element is equal to "Product BBB".

thank you E.Wiest, it works as expected.
